# sorting using np array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on program for school that requires me to use python. I have never used python before so it has been a bit of a challenge. I am trying to write code to calculate avg. wait time, avg. turn around, and average response time for shortest job first scheduling algorithm. I have created a np array to store the information for each process. the columns from left to right are positionID, arrival time, burst time. I need to be able to sort the columns based on burst time where the arrival time is less than or equal to a clock. is this possible using argsort? For this set of numbers it wouldn't be a problem but would like to make it work with all sets of numbers

```
import numpy as np
pid = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
at  = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
bt  = np.array([8,4,9,5,2])
arr5 = np.array(list(zip(pid,at,bt)))
sortedarr = arr5[arr5[:,1].argsort()]
print('array sorted by arival')
print(sortedarr)
clock = sortedarr[0,2]
print('clock = ',clock)
sortedarr = np.delete(sortedarr,0,0)
print('array after removing finished process')
print(sortedarr)
sortedarr = sortedarr[sortedarr[:,2].argsort()]
print('array after sorting by burst time')
print(sortedarr)
```

output:

```
array sorted by arival
[[1 0 8]
 [2 1 4]
 [3 2 9]
 [4 3 5]
 [5 4 2]]
clock =  8
array after removing finished process
[[2 1 4]
 [3 2 9]
 [4 3 5]
 [5 4 2]]
array after sorting by burst time
[[5 4 2]
 [2 1 4]
 [4 3 5]
 [3 2 9]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAzCt.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you expected? please explain more or prepare an  example that shows what you expected

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, the goal is to slice the array where a condition (for *arrival time*) is satisfied, and then sort the array based on the *burst time*. For example, if we want rows of the array which have `arrival time <= 2` and then sort it:

```
clock = 2

# sortedarr:  [[1 0 8]
#              [2 1 4]
#              [3 2 9]
#              [4 3 5]
#              [5 4 2]]

sortedarr = sortedarr[sortedarr[:, 1] <= clock]

# sortedarr:  [[1 0 8]
#              [2 1 4]
#              [3 2 9]]

sortedarr = sortedarr[sortedarr[:, 2].argsort()]

# sortedarr:  [[2 1 4]
#              [1 0 8]
#              [3 2 9]]
```

Hope it be the answer. If not, please clarify the needs.